# who can give me some suggestion on learn the kernel of linux?

Tags: operating-system

Recently,I want to lean the linux OS,but whit the awful source code I feel that I'v lost in the source code and I haven't got anything.so ,who can tell me some of your experiences on learn linux OS or some advise.thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you can read the website [Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org) and try to learn to build a Linux from source code.